# Why does Swashbuckle/Swagger include a variable name in a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, class, swagger, swashbuckle

For an older net framework project I am using Swashbuckle 5.6.0.  A strange thing happens when I use a class for the get argument. It adds the variable name to the parameter.

This means the consumer of the api has to add "record." to the front of every argument.  Really inconvenient.

What is the explanation for this behavior?

[image: Here is what it looks like in swagger]

[image: The definition in the controller:]

This is POCO class:

```
  public class AssetTransactionAllAssetsSearchRecord2
    {
        public AssetTransactionAllAssetsSearchRecord2() { }
        
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime FromCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToCreated { get; set; }
        public long? DocumentId { get; set; }

        public long AssetId { get; set; }
        public long HostingAssetId { get; set; }
        public long SystemAssetId { get; set; }
        public long CustomerAssetId { get; set; }

        public string AssetCode { get; set; }
        public string HostingAssetCode { get; set; }
        public string SystemAssetCode { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAssetCode { get; set; }

        public string AssetName { get; set; }
        public string HostingAssetName { get; set; }
        public string SystemAssetName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAssetName { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the Swagger config:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using VI_Web;
using Swashbuckle.Application;
using Swashbuckle.Swagger;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http.Description;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace VI_Web
{
    class AuthTokenOperation : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
        {
            swaggerDoc.paths.Add("/token", new PathItem
            {
                post = new Operation
                {
                    tags = new List<string> { "UserAuth" },
                    consumes = new List<string>
                {
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                    parameters = new List<Parameter> {
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "grant_type",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData",
                        @default = "password"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_id",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_secret",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "database",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    }

                }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {
                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "VI_Web");
                        c.ApiKey("Token")
                        .Description("Filling bearer token here")
                        .Name("Authorization")
                        .In("header");
                        c.DocumentFilter<AuthTokenOperation>();
                    })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    {
                        c.EnableApiKeySupport("Authorization", "header");
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the name of the table in the database, not the variable name.

Comment: @jdweng No it isn't, this has nothing to do with the database. Show me where the database is here.

Comment: @GeorgeHelmke How have you configured Swagger?

Comment: @DavidG : A record is a rows of a database : api has to add "record."

Comment: @jdweng A record is also a circular bit of vinyl that plays music but I don't see mention of that anywhere. Just because you see a word doesn't mean it is important.

Comment: About "records":  When I started this project I decided to name all of the "models" records instead.  With ASP.NET MVC, the "model" ends up doing too little and too much ends up in the controller.  I was trying to avoid that, ha ha.  Have I regretted this decision?  Many times.  But it did sort of solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me sort this out :)
I have put the config in the issue up top.

Comment: Because it is `GET` method with complext type as `record` parameter and I would guess this is how old ASP handled binding complex types as get parameters.

Comment: @GuruStron - I was afraid this was the case.  Still hoping there is a configurable parameter somewhere.

Comment: @GuruStron - It is looking to me like your comment will be the accepted answer.  If you can put it in as answer then I can flag it as such.  Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that this is not  Swashbuckle issue (assuming that querying the endpoint actually works) but how your ASP.NET setup handles GET request handlers with "complex" type passed as parameter (`record`). You can try flattening the type into separate endpoint parameters:

```
... GetWithAssets(long id, DateTime fromCreated, ...)
```

Or maybe using `FromUriAttribute` as mentioned in the [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri) docs, which based on the example should flatten the type without parameter name prefix:

```
... GetWithAssets([FromUri] AssetTransactionAllAssetsSearchRecord2 record)
```

Also you can turn your endpoint into POST and accept JSON body which is quite popular approach for search-like endpoints.

Comment: I just ended up with separate parameters, it works for the end user. New versions of Swashbuckle handle this just fine, so I am accepting this legacy solution will be done this way.